# stub setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have a function wait

```
async function wait(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

And I call this wait like this: `await wait(5000);` from a different function.

I am writing unit test cases and it always executes wait and each test case waits for 5s.

How do I stub the setTimeout using Sinon?

I tried:

```
  // Skip setTimeOut
  clock = sinon.useFakeTimers({
    now: Date.now(),
    toFake: ['setTimeout']
  });
  await clock.tickAsync(4000);
  await Promise.resolve();
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Why would you? It's a standard-mandated function. Plus, this is Javascript, you don't need a mock library to overwrite a global function...

Comment: @JaredSmith Unit test case execution is delayed by 50 seconds since I have 10 unit test case for that method.

Comment: So pass it a time of 0. It will fire on the next tick of the event loop. Then run your test on a 1 ms delay, instead of 4000.

Comment: But passing 0 from unit test case won't affect the actual function behavior.

Comment: You are severely overthinking this. If its important to test the behavior with a 5 second delay,  the you're going to have to eat those 5 seconds for every test that requires it. If it isn't, pass a zero and be done with it. If that can't be done with the way you have written the code, then rewrite the code. All that being said, `globalThis.setTimeout = (cb) => cb();`

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, you were right. I was overthinking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related post: [setTimeout not triggered while using Sinon's fake timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048799/settimeout-not-triggered-while-using-sinons-fake-timers/43048888#43048888)

Github issue: https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/issues/194#issuecomment-395224370

You can solve this in two ways.

1. Consider whether your test case requires a delay of 5000ms.

The unit test should test the code logic, it's not integration tests. So, maybe you just need to make an assertion check the `wait` function is to be called with parameter. It's enough. We don't need to wait for 5000ms delay in the test case.

2. If you insist want to use `sinon.useFakeTimers()` and `clock.tick(5000)`.

From the related post, we can do it like this:

`index.ts`:

```js
async function wait(time: number, clock?) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
    clock && clock.tick(time);
  });
}

export async function main(time, /* for testing */ clock?) {
  await wait(time, clock);
  console.log('main');
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import sinon, { SinonFakeTimers } from 'sinon';

describe('60617715', () => {
  let clock: SinonFakeTimers;
  beforeEach(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    clock.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    await main(5000, clock);
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
  60617715
main
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (9ms)
```