# sinon useFakeTimers not resolving last promise-timeout, test times out

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I want to test my logic and ensure that I don't exceed a limit of X requests every X seconds. Using `mocha@^9.1.3`, `chai@^4.3.4` and `sinon@^12.0.1`, latest versions as of this comment.

I've read answers to very similar problems to mine, tried applying the knowledge gained but to no avail:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951 — great explanation as to the *why*, however I must've misunderstood something
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55448441 — similar to 1.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048888, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60629795 — adding `clock.tickAsync` inside the `wait` utility function would not let me step through the code

I have a `wait` utility function looking like this:

```js
const wait = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

and my code to reproduce my issue in my test file looks like (please do read comments in code):

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';
import got from 'got';

describe('sinon usefaketimers promise-timeouts', () => {
  let clock: sinon.SinonFakeTimers;

  beforeEach(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers({ toFake: ['setTimeout'] });
    // i've also tried this
    // clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    clock.restore();
  });

  it('steps through all promise-timeouts manually', async () => {
    const main = async () => {
      console.log('starting');
      await wait(1000);
      console.log('waited 1s');
      await wait(1000);
      console.log('waited 2s');
      // switching out `got()` below to `await Promise.resolve()`
      // finishes the test successfully
      await got('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').json(); // <-- switch to `await Promise.resolve()` makes it work
      console.log('request done');
      await wait(1000);
      console.log('waited 3s');
    };

    const promise = main();

    await clock.tickAsync(1000); // I have tried adding different combinations
    await clock.tickAsync(1000); // of `await Promise.resolve()` after the tick(s)
    await clock.tickAsync(1000);

    return promise;
  });
});
```

and the resulting output is, (it hangs after "request done", missing the last line "waited 3s"):

```
starting
waited 1s
waited 2s
request done
```

Note, I've tried switching out `got` to `superagent` and `node-fetch` without any success. I'm not entirely sure why they would be any different from `Promise.resolve` as they are all promises returned and `await`ed on.

Really hope to clear up whatever I didn't get from reading above questions (and so many other threads) from yesterday and todays debugging.

Comment: Well (ignoring the first two seconds) the code does call `got()`, then calls `clock.tickAsync(1000);`, and then only after `got()` fulfills it does `wait(1000);`. You could mock `got` and make it fulfill immediately, or have it call `tickAsync` *after* the http request finishes? Not sure what the goal of your test is here.

Comment: It might help the understanding if you would intersperse those `await clock.tickAsync(1000);` with some more logs

Comment: Thanks for reading my post @Bergi. This is a contrived example of my code, but the problem remains the same. I make two kinds of requests and once all is done I recursively call `main` from inside itself to go through all pagination data. First request is fetching data, second is fetching more data based on data from the first response, this is at least 1 more request to be made but could potentially be several. I have the `wait`'s to throttle requests done to stay within "X requests every X seconds". The 2x `wait` above at beginning could be reduced to 1 (as explained above) but issue remains

Comment: @Bergi, I did try to `nock` it, assuming it should give the same result as mocking `got`, with no success. You're right it does call `got()` and resolves the promise after 2nd `tickAsync` but does not continue past 3rd `wait` with a third `tickAsync`. I have tried to put `await Promise.resolve()` in between the 2nd and 3rd `tickAsync` wanting to flush what's in PromiseJobs queue (`got` call) but didn't get that to work either. The two initial `wait` in above code snippet is just to convey that `tickAsync` does work with my `wait` func, however only 1 in the beginning is needed